# finitely many lines in a plane

Tags: plane-geometry

There are finitely many lines in a plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. $\textbf{None of them is parallel}$. For each line $L$ which intersects with other lines say at $A_1$, $A_2$, $\cdots$ , $A_n$ in the consecutive order, it is called (1) well-divided (w.d.) if $A_1A_2 = A_2A_3 = \cdots = A_{n-1}A_n$;
(2) geometrically-divided (g.d.) if $A_{i+1}A_{i+2}/A_iA_{i+1}=k$ for all $i$.
(3) monotone if $A_iA_{i+1}$'s are monotone increasing or decreasing.

For (2) and (3) they must be in the consecutive order.

A well-divided line is trivial if there are only one or two intersections. Similarly, g.d. lines and monotone lines are trivial if there are three intersections or less.

Recently I proved the following result:

Theorem. If all lines are well-divided, then there is at most one non-trivial well-divided line.

My questions are, what if all lines are g.d. lines with the same ratio $k$? What if all lines are g.d. lines with arbitrary ratios? What if all lines are monotone?

I only have some partial results.

Has anyone considered these problems before? Can anyone give me some references about these problems? Thanks.

Comment: How is it possible that there are more than three well-divided lines in the plane without having two of them parallel?

Comment: @Crostul When they all concur?  This may be the only possible situation.

Comment: @HaoranChen Can you provide a proof of your theorem, so that we can better understand your question.

Comment: If there are n>3 lines, they are either all concurrent, or n-1 lines are concurrent, and the other line is well divided by the n-1 lines.

Comment: @Batominovski I have submitted my result to a journal and it's still under review. I can send you a copy if you like. The proof uses an idea that is similar to the proof of the famous Sylvester's problem and is about 4 pages.

Comment: Have you posted on arXiv (https://arxiv.org/)?  If you haven't planned to do that, you can also send a copy to me at nahtisan@aim.com.  Your problem looks very interesting.

Comment: @Batominovski I'm trying to post it on arXiv. I will let you know as soon as I post it.